# R: extract names of partially named vector

Tags: r, vector, names

I have a vector that is partially named. All values (and names) are distinct.

```
my_vec <- c('one',
           'two' = '2',
           'three' = '3')
```

Sometimes I need the values i.e. `unique(my_vec)` which returns `c("one","2","3")`. I now need the
"opposite" that is: `c("one","two", "three")`.  Note that `names` is insufficient because the vector is partially named.

**Is there a base R or tidy way to return the names of vector elements where available and vector values otherwise?**

Apologies, this feels like something that should have an easily accessible answer on here but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: `ifelse(names(my_vec) == "", my_vec, names(my_vec))`?

Comment: Thanks! I guess easy enough to put this in a function. :)

Comment: you can also make use of the `nzchar` function `ifelse(nzchar(nms<-names(my_vec)), nms, my_vec)`